# Beguiling Influence replica skill

Tags: dnd-5e, warlock, eldritch-invocations

I have a player with a warlock character proficient in Deception.

Do the rules allows for this warlock to take the Beguiling Influence invocation and replace Deception with another skill they are not proficient in (in this case, Insight).

Or does the text on replacing skills or tools from multiple sources only apply to skills or tools to backgrounds?